# How to add custom php page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am making custom **CRUD** method in WordPress so i need to add custom php page in WordPress.
There is no one option like a template in add new page option. so how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ Create custom template

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Your_Template_Name
*/

// YOUR PHP
```

2/ Create PAGE in Back Office with YOUR_TEMPLATE

OR

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages